# MySQL - number of days worked within date range

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following data:

```
 empid | officeid |     doj
-------+----------+------------
  19   |    112   | 2012-05-06
  26   |    112   | 2012-10-16
  35   |    112   | 2014-05-01
  17   |    112   | 2015-12-14
  19   |    169   | 2016-10-07
  26   |    146   | 2015-08-07
  42   |    102   | 2016-06-07
  35   |    135   | 2016-10-15
  26   |    112   | 2016-10-20
```

(doj = Date of Joining). I need to get a report of employees with number of days worked in an office, for a particular period. For example, I want a report of **Office ID 112** for **October 2016**. So the result should be like this:

```
 empid |  days
-------+-------
  35   |   14  (moved to another office on October 15th)
  17   |   31  (complete month)
  26   |   11  (October 20 to 31)
  42   |   31  (complete month)
```

Employee 19 should not come as he is not in the office 112 now. What I tried:

```
select sh.empid,datediff(
    greatest(last_day('2016-10-01'),
    (select doj from servicehistory where empid=sh.empid and date<sh.date
        order by date desc limit 1)
    ),date
) as days from servicehistory sh where sh.office='112' and date=(
    if(
        ((select count(date) from servicehistory where empid=sh.empid and
            date between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-31')>0),
        (select date from servicehistory where empid=sh.empid and
            date between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-31' limit 1),
        (select max(date) from servicehistory where empid=sh.empid and
            office=sh.office and date<=last_day('2016-10-01'))
    )
)
```

But it is not giving desired results. It is giving days more than 31 and employees not currently in the office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select (case when tmp.doj<='2016-10-01' then DATEDIFF(last_day('2016-10-01'),'2016-10-01')
else DATEDIFF(last_day('2016-10-01'),tmp.doj) end )as days,tmp.emp_id from (
select emp_id,max(doj)as doj from emp e group by emp_id)tmp
```

Try this and alter as per your requirement.